Change in rectangles after ol-cesium 2.15.0
I am using polygons in my website, built with Openlayers and ol-cesium.
These polygons used to be correct when in 3D (i.e. lines are not supposed to be straight in the 3D view).

This used to work fine until ol-cesium 2.14.0. Now I have tried to upgrade, and with 2.15.x onwards, polygon lines appear straight (i.e. screen-straight and not world-straight). I have also tried updating Openlayers and Cesium; nothing makes any difference.

var geometry = new MultiPolygon(this.paths[i]);
if (JMap.projection != 'EPSG:4326') {
    geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', JMap.projection);
}
geometry.set('olcs.polygon_kind', 'rectangle');
newpolygons.push(new Feature({
    geometry: geometry,
    colour: i
}));

Is a behaviour change which I can revert with some flag? I have created a ticket in case it is a regression: https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/issues/1214

It looks like 'olcs.polygon_kind' should be set on the feature instead of (or perhaps as well as) on the geometry https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/commit/c5100f648223c11aa563dd9ee1d53b7955b6c47e#diff-e8d7b66d5f2cbe58ce300a0f3deb9827d024aecd2455dcbed82d6265b84019c8R516

Thanks for the pointer! Looking at the diff from 2.14 I saw what needed to be fixed.

By looking at the diff in github, we can see 2 breaking changes:

'rectangle' needs to be set on the feature instead of the geometry
The property is now called 'olcs_polygon_kind' instead of 'olcs.polygon_kind'

So the fixed code would be as follows:
var geometry = new MultiPolygon(this.paths[i]);
if (JMap.projection != 'EPSG:4326') {
    geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', JMap.projection);
}
var feature = new Feature({
    geometry: geometry,
    colour: i
});
feature.set('olcs_polygon_kind', 'rectangle');
newpolygons.push(feature);

